# Multiple vs single texture blending

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I have a fragment color which is the result of 4 different draws, each painting a different color. I have C1+C2+C3+C4=CR using a glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). This is perfectly fine and correct.

Suppose I only have the red and alpha channels, if my 4 writes are (0.1,0.4),(0.6,0.3),(0.1,0.4),(0.6,0.3) the resulting color will be (0,313,0.3574), since (0.1,0.4)+(0.6,0.3)=(0.25,0.37) using the above blend function, blending then (0.1,0.4) will result in (0.19,0.382) and after the final (0.6,0.3) we have (0.313,0.3574).

Now the rendering code changed for RTT and I have two distinct textures, one with C1+C2 and the other with C3+C4 (always using glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)). Blending the two textures together using the same blending function obviously yelds to a different CR. Seems like I cant figure out how to achieve the same CR color, splitting the rendering in 2 textures. I tried several configurations on paper but I cant find a proper formula to get the same value.

Using the above example, in both textures I have (0.1,0.4)+(0.6,0.3) = (0.25,0.37) with the same blending function. Blending two (0.25,0.37) using that function will not result in (0.313,0.3574), which is the value I want to achieve.

Comment: That is because C1+C2+C3+C4 is transformed into a composite function: mix (C4, mix (C3, mix (C2, mix (C1, fb, C1.A), C2.A), C3.A), C4.A) when you use that blend function. It is order dependent, you cannot break it up that way. The same way that f(g(h(i(x)))) != f(g(x))+h(i(x)).

Comment: That is correct, do you think there is a way to achieve this?

Comment: Using 2 textures? I cannot think of any. You need the individual colors for everything but the first blend to properly order these operations. You can reduce it to 3 textures, but at that point you might be better off just implementing this in a single fragment shader pass instead of blending multiple passes.

Comment: Agree, think Ill address this in the fragment shader, thanks